# Improper Integral , Transform Fourier

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve an improper integral :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega|\hat{G}(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega$$

where the function is it:

$$
G(x) =
\begin{cases}
2-\frac{2x^2}{\pi^2} &  -\pi<x \leq0 
\\ cosx+1 & 0<x \leq \pi
\end{cases}
$$

I thought about fixing it using the Plancherel's theorem. But there is a problem that is , there is an $\omega$ before of module. Then i think that to solve this integral, i must to do a derivative of function G(x) than integrate the module of the derivative . Is the reasoning correct? Thank you so much

Comment: What is the Fourier transform of $H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(-y) G(x-y)dy$ ?  What is the Fourier transform of $H'(x)$ ?